# Infinite 301 redirects after definitions in "Redirections" plugin?

Tags: plugins, redirect, urls

I have just finished setting up a few 301 redirections using the "Redirections" plugin on the new site, as a preparation for moving from the old site.
Currently, the new site is defined as a subdomain and eventually, it will be defined under the top level domain name of the site.
Right now, any original URL (from the old site) I run on the subdomain of the new site results in a loop of the browser until getting an error.

For example:

A URL from the old site:

http://www.example.com/page.html

The redirection definition:

/page.html -> /page

So that right now, under the subdomain, running this URL:

http://dev.example.com/page.html

Should redirect to:

http://dev.example.com/page

As mentioned, when going to the old page on the new site, it loops.

I want to know if this happens because the new site is defined now on a subdomain and when it's defined on the TLD, this situation will not occur.

If that's not the issue, I need to know the reason and to resolve it before I go live with the new site.

Comment: What is this plugin URL?

Comment: If you're asking about the plugin itself that I'm using in this case, this is it: https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/

Comment: The plugin name is Redirection w/o `s` at the end, so I was not sure. Can you copy/paste your rules?

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it!!

The right way to define a redirection when the content of the URL (either the original or the new one) is in Hebrew, is simply define then URL-encoded.

For example:

```
/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%9A-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA.html
```

->

```
/%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%A1%D7%9A-%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%90%D7%99%D7%95%D7%AA/
```

That's it! This works like a charm and like it should.

For encoding and decoding URL special characters (like Hebrew), you can use this simple, yet very helpful online tool:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder